# XSLT Loops and Ifs

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a snippet of an XML Response as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Envelope>
    <Body>
        <Response>
            <Result>
                <ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>
                <ErrorDescription>Success</ErrorDescription>
                <Instances>
                    <Instance>
                      <ID>3333</ID>
                      <RoundCode>AM</RoundCode>
                      <ScheduleName>Tue</ScheduleName>
                      <Date>2017-10-24T00:00:00</Date>
                      <SlotsFree>0</SlotsFree>
                      <SlotsTaken>10</SlotsTaken>
                    </Instance>
                    <Instance>
                        <ID>4444</ID>
                        <RoundCode>PM</RoundCode>
                        <ScheduleName>Tue</ScheduleName>
                        <Date>2017-10-24T00:00:00</Date>
                        <SlotsFree>10</SlotsFree>
                        <SlotsTaken>0</SlotsTaken>
                    </Instance>
                </Instances>
            </Result>
        </Response>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

I need it to show all AM slots if they are less than 10, and if they are greater than or equal to 10, show the PM slots instead (For the selected day (In this case, Tue)). I have tried looping through, but because the data being passed to it will always meet one of the criteria, and therefore displays both AM and PM. I need the code to display AM, and if it can't, then display PM. Given this a try with the XSL:when and XSL:if and still can't seem to get any working transformations for this.

My Current XSLT and HTML is below, if anyone has any suggestions, this would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>ScheduleName</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>SlotsFree</th>
      <th>SlotsTaken</th>
      <th>RoundCode</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="Envelope/Body/Response/Result/Instances/Instance">

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="ScheduleName='Mon' and contains(RoundCode,'AM') and SlotsTaken &lt; 10">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="ID"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="ScheduleName"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(substring(Date,1,10),9,2),'/',substring(substring(Date,1,10),6,2),'/',substring(substring(Date,1,10),1,4))"/><xsl:value-of select="concat(' (',SlotsFree,' Slots Remaining!)')"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="SlotsFree"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="SlotsTaken"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="RoundCode"/></td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: but you are only checking for AM so why would it show PM?

Comment: It does only check for AM on this copy at the moment. I have snipped out my attempts at doing this as there is too many. Basically I need to check if AM SlotsTaken is less than 10 (Then display AM), otherwise, display PM.

Comment: Is there a requirement to not display PM slots if AM are available for the day?

Comment: Yep, thats correct. I only need to display PM if AM is not available - and if AM is not available, only PM should be shown.

Comment: Will the XML only ever have one day in, or can it have more than one day?

Comment: In most occasions, there will be multiple of the Instance Nodes, with different Days assigned. E.g. AM/PM for Monday, AM/PM for Tuesday etc. But there will always be an AM, and always be a PM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a key to look up `Instance` elements by `Date`

```
 <xsl:key name="days" match="Instance" use="Date" />
```

Then, to get days with `AM` slots which are less than 10, or `PM` otherwise, you can add a condition to the `xsl:for-each`

Try this XSTL

```
<xsl:for-each 
     select="Envelope/Body/Response/Result/Instances/Instance
             [(RoundCode = 'AM' and SlotsTaken &lt; 10) 
                or (RoundCode = 'PM' and not(key('days', Date)[RoundCode = 'AM' and SlotsTaken &lt; 10]))]">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="days" match="Instance" use="Date" />
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>ScheduleName</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>SlotsFree</th>
      <th>SlotsTaken</th>
      <th>RoundCode</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="Envelope/Body/Response/Result/Instances/Instance[(RoundCode = 'AM' and SlotsTaken &lt; 10) or (RoundCode = 'PM' and not(key('days', Date)[RoundCode = 'AM' and SlotsTaken &lt; 10]))]">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="ID"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="ScheduleName"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(substring(Date,1,10),9,2),'/',substring(substring(Date,1,10),6,2),'/',substring(substring(Date,1,10),1,4))"/><xsl:value-of select="concat(' (',SlotsFree,' Slots Remaining!)')"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="SlotsFree"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="SlotsTaken"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="RoundCode"/></td>
      </tr>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It doesn't appear to be working for me with that data on the W3 site (https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog_if) nor my page with the code provided and example code. Do you have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: The w3schools website does not like the use of `&lt;` in the expression. Instead of `SlotsTaken &lt; 10` try doing `not(SlotsTaken &gt;= 10)`

Answer (score 0):

Using version 2.0, this works on http://xslttest.appspot.com/ but not my FF browser, I'm not sure why.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>ScheduleName</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>SlotsFree</th>
        <th>SlotsTaken</th>
        <th>RoundCode</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="Envelope/Body/Response/Result/Instances/Instance[SlotsTaken &lt; 10 and (contains(RoundCode,'AM') or contains(RoundCode,'PM'))]" group-by="ScheduleName">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="./ID"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="./ScheduleName"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(substring(./Date,1,10),9,2),'/',substring(substring(./Date,1,10),6,2),'/',substring(substring(./Date,1,10),1,4))"/><xsl:value-of select="concat(' (',./SlotsFree,' Slots Remaining!)')"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="./SlotsFree"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="./SlotsTaken"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="./RoundCode"/></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each-group>            
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```